# Indesign running-header character style doesnt work if characters are the number in a list

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and in the paragraph style is set that the number `[1, 2, 3, 4...]` is of character **style A**. Now I set a variable for the character style A and it doesn't show up the number as expected. If I set some text with the character style A it works as expected.

The problem is only when the character style is in a list number....

## I've found:

> "[The Running Header (Character Style)](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1349397)" variable will only find a
>   character style that has been applied manually or is part of a
>   standard nested style. It will not detect character styles that are
>   part of a nested line style, GREP style, or any character style used
>   to style the numbers in a numbered list."

**Anyway to workaround this issue?**

The objective of all of this is the following:

- Each chapter has a letter and each chapter has various sub-chapters, that I think are named sections, which looks like this G1, where the G is the chapter and 1 is the section...
- Then there are the pages that starts at each section so: `G1 1, G1 2, G1 3, G2 1, G2 2...`

Comment: any luck with this? just ran into it.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the exact same problem, and have two solutions.

## Solution 1

Follow this tutorial, which has a workaround based on cross-references.
http://luckylion.de/vasco/tutorials/indesign_beyond_the_thesis/running_headline_numbering.php

A bit of work though, as you manually have to add cross-references for each subtitle.

## Solution 2

Apply "Convert Numbering to Text" to everything when the document is finished. If you have a character style applied to your list numbers, this will make InDesign recognize it. The numbers in the list will, of course, no longer update atomatically if you add more later.

Comment: Hi 22633, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! Could you, even shortly, give a summary of the solution given in the tutorial you link to? That way, the answer will still be valuable later, in case the link breaks. Thanks!